# problem with string manipulation function retrieving URL

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

i build a simple **scraper** to get me links from other website
my problem now is to getting the link it self not all of the content

```
<a onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','namobile.naughtyamerica.com']);" href="http://www.wwww.com/track/MTA3ODQxLjEyLjQwLjQwLjAuMC4wLjAuMA/freeporn3/lisa_ann6/7535/"><img class="aligncenter size-full" title="Lisa Ann" src="http://www.www.com/upload/source/mfhm/lisawill/lisawillhor_gmna_big_img3.jpg" alt="Lisa Ann" width="313" height="223" /></a>
```

here the image and its link i need to get the link only in a variable to be like that

```
$url = "http://www.wwww.com/track/MTA3ODQxLjEyLjQwLjQwLjAuMC4wLjAuMA/freeporn3/lisa_ann6/7535/";
```

that its it thank you

Answer (score 0):

Use queryPath, Simple HTML DOM Parser or other PHP libraries for navigating in DOM document

Comment: how should i if the A tag have no id ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [PHP Query library](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/), and [attr method](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/wiki/Attributes) if you are familiar with CSS selectors.

```
<?php 
echo pq('a')->attr('href');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$html = <<< EOF
<a onclick="javascript:_gaq.push(['_trackEvent','outbound-article','namobile.naughtyamerica.com']);" href="http://www.wwww.com/track/MTA3ODQxLjEyLjQwLjQwLjAuMC4wLjAuMA/freeporn3/lisa_ann6/7535/"><img class="aligncenter size-full" title="Lisa Ann" src="http://www.www.com/upload/source/mfhm/lisawill/lisawillhor_gmna_big_img3.jpg" alt="Lisa Ann" width="313" height="223" /></a>
EOF;

preg_match_all('/<a onclick.*?href="(.*?)"/im', $html, $url, PREG_PATTERN_ORDER);
$url = $url[1][0];


echo $url // echo's "http://www.wwww.com/track/MTA3ODQxLjEyLjQwLjQwLjAuMC4wLjAuMA/freeporn3/lisa_ann6/7535/"
```